# Python-QDateEdit event

Tags: python, events, pyqt4

I am working on python plugins.I designed my form using pyqt4 designer.
I used **Qdatedit** control with **calendar popup** property to true.I wanted to call one function on selecting date from qdateedit.
I tried something like

```
self.connect(self.dateEdit, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.start_date_dateedit)
self.connect(self.dateEdit, SIGNAL("selectionChanged()"), self.start_date_dateedit)
```

to call function **start_date_dateedit**.But no success.
What is the **event** to call a function from qdateedit??

How to set **current date** into **qdatedit**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QDateEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdateedit.html) inherits from [`QDateTimeEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetimeedit.html), so you can use:

```
void dateChanged ( const QDate & date )
void dateTimeChanged ( const QDateTime & datetime )
void timeChanged ( const QTime & time )
```

You are probably looking for:

```
self.dateEdit.dateChanged.connect(self.start_date_dateedit)
```

Comment: @poonam: `self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())`